# Change element attributes and re-render

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating image elements directly into a div.

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
function createImages(){
  for(var i = 0, piece = 1; i < 10; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < 10; j++, piece++){
        var lin = i*100, col = j*100;
        var img = document.createElement("IMG");
        img.src = '../'+piece+'.jpg';
        img.style.position = "absolute";
        img.style.top = ''+lin+'px';
        img.style.left = ''+col+'px';                       
        img.style.border = '1px solid #000000';                     
        myDiv.appendChild(img);
    }
  }
}
```

This works just fine!
Now I'm trying give the images an onclick event that calls a function that changes some attributes, but I don't know if I'm adding the onclick event the right way.

```
img.onclick = change();
```

Also I don't know how to re-render the images automaticaly after the changes take effect.

It needs to be in simple Javascript.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Remove the parenthesis: `img.onclick = change;`

Comment: `img.onclick = change();` is assigning the return value of the `change` function.  You may instead want to assign `change` itself, like so: `img.onclick = change;`.  This will mean `change()` is executed when the image is clicked.

Comment: Many thanks all of you!

Just one more thing, what if I want to add another function which has a parameter to my onclick event. Lets say I did: 

    `img.onclick = change;`

And now I want to add:

    `retrieveClass(this.className);`

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
img.onclick = change();
```

to

```
img.onclick = change;
```

In the first case you're assigning the value returned by the `change()` function to `onclick`. In the second case, you're assigning the `change` function itself to `onclick`.

Also, there is no need for your code to actively do any re-rendering. The browser takes care of this for you as you manipulate the DOM.

Comment: Many thanks!

Just one more thing, what if I want to add another function which has a parameter to my onclick event. Lets say I did: 

    `img.onclick = change;`

And now I want to add:

    `retrieveClass(this.className);`

Can you help me?

Comment: You should open a new question for a new question. But I think an anonymous function will do what you want: `img.onclick = function(){ retrieveClass(this.className); };`